# Trigger that increment value from another table

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

When a new invoice is issued, the "sold" attribute in distributor table needs to increment.

invoice_ty is as follow:

```
create or replace type invoice_ty as object(
Invoice_no VARCHAR(10),
distributor ref distributor_ty,
customer ref customer_ty,
price NUMBER(6, 2)
);
 
Create or replace type Distributor_ty as object (
VAT VARCHAR(15),
Seq_No NUMBER,
Sold NUMBER,
Address Distributor_address_ty)
NOT FINAL;
```

This trigger return mutating table error:

```
create or replace trigger increment_sold
after insert on invoice
for each row
BEGIN
update distributor set sold = sold + 1  where distributor.vat = treat(:new.distributor as ref distributor_ty).vat;
END;
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use a compound trigger and collect the distributors to update from the `invoice` table into a collection in the `AFTER EACH ROW` clause and then update the `distributors` table in the `AFTER STATEMENT` clause:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER increment_sold
FOR INSERT ON invoice
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  v_vats SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
    v_vat DISTRIBUTOR.VAT%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT DEREF(:NEW.distributor).vat
    INTO   v_vat
    FROM   DUAL;

    v_vats.EXTEND;
    v_vats(v_vats.COUNT) := v_vat;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;  
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO distributor dst
    USING (
      SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS vat,
             COUNT(*) AS num_sold
      FROM   TABLE(v_vats)
      GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
    ) src
    ON (src.vat = dst.vat)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET    sold = dst.sold + src.num_sold;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nsGVytEC)

Comment: OK..could you explain this trigger?

Comment: @mikerug88 As stated in the answer, in the `AFTER EACH ROW` clause of the trigger, collect all the inserted `VAT` values into a collection. Then, in the `AFTER STATEMENT` clause of the trigger, use that collection to update the `sold` column for each `vat` value in the collection.